# Synchronize jobs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I have 4 methods: A, B1, B2, B3 and want to encapsulate their execution in separate jobs. A generates result that B uses so A must be finished before starting B, and if A fails don't start B. Also for performance reasons I don't want B1, B2, B3 to run concurrently, but sequential, start B2 when B1 is finished, but they don't share results so if some B fails, start other normally. I don't want any retry on fail, just one attempt for each. So execution order is A->B1->B2->B3.

In docs there is not much about synchronizing mechanisms, so it's not obvious how to implement this. I found Queue::after handler, which as I understand fires on every job end, how do you filter which job? By class `if(is_a($event->job , 'JobAClass'))...`?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#job-events

```
    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->job->payload()
    });
```

Comment: My question might seem stupid but why do you need to have 4 separate jobs when all 4 methods are executed one after another?

Comment: Those functions are long lasting, performing number of http requests, and cpu-consuming tasks, such as img rendering, making them jobs - separate processes provides additional layer of reliability comparing to one long-lasting script call.

Comment: Reliability is added by properly handling user input, exceptions, and I/O operations. You don't gain any reliability by splitting a long task into two shorter tasks run in a sequence. But I understand that this is not what you came here looking for.

Comment: If B1 gets unhanded exception, B2 and B3 wont run, with jobs B1, B2, B3 are independent. Execution order and conditions may evolve in future. Long scripts are bad practice.